# Отправка selectmenu в канал без команды

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Столкнулся с проблемой, что после определённого отрезка времени выдаёт ошибку взаимодействия. Нужно как-то сделать так, чтобы selectmenu можно было пользоваться всегда и не нужно было постоянно отправлять команду ($faq в моём случае) в канал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сам код:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import View


class Dropdown(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):

        options = [
            discord.SelectOption(
                label='Вопрос1', 
                emoji='<:1_:1061684102794850305>'),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label='Вопрос2',
                emoji='<:2_:1061684134126289016>'),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label='Вопрос3', 
                emoji='<:3_:1061684130833764522>'),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label='Вопрос4', 
                emoji='<:4_:1061684126010322984>'),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label='Вопрос5', 
                emoji='<:5_:1061684123950919690>'),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label='Вопрос6', 
                emoji='<:6_:1061684119957950527>'),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label='Вопрос7', 
                emoji='<:7_:1061684116896096296>'),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label='Вопрос8', 
                emoji='<:8_:1061684115054796880>'),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label='Вопрос9', 
                emoji='<:9_:1061684111783231518>'),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label='Вопрос10', 
                emoji='<:10:1061684108079661107>'),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label='Вопрос11', 
                emoji='<:11:1061684106095767627>'),
        ]

        super().__init__(placeholder='Ответы на часто задаваемые вопросы', min_values=1, max_values=1, options=options)

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        if self.values[0] == 'Вопрос1':
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                content='ответ1', 
                ephemeral=True)
        if self.values[0] == 'Вопрос2':          
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                content='ответ2', 
                ephemeral=True)
        if self.values[0] == 'Вопрос3':
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                content='ответ3',
                ephemeral=True)
        if self.values[0] == 'Вопрос4':
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                content='ответ4', 
                ephemeral=True)
        if self.values[0] == 'Вопрос5':
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                content='ответ5',
                ephemeral=True)
        if self.values[0] == 'Вопрос6':
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                content='ответ6',
                ephemeral=True)
        if self.values[0] == 'Вопрос7':
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                content='ответ7',
                ephemeral=True)
        if self.values[0] == 'Вопрос8':
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                content='ответ8',
                ephemeral=True)
        if self.values[0] == 'Вопрос9':
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                content='ответ9',
                ephemeral=True)
        if self.values[0] == 'Вопрос10':
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                content='ответ10',
                ephemeral=True)
        if self.values[0] == 'Вопрос11':
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                content='ответ11',
                ephemeral=True)


class DropdownView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.add_item(Dropdown())


class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True


super().__init__(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('$'), intents=intents)


async def on_ready(self):
    print(f'Работает - {self.user} (ID: {self.user.id})')
    print('------')


bot = Bot()


@bot.command()
async def faq(ctx, member:discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.author

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Вопрос-Ответы!", description="Вы можете получить ответы на интересующие Вас вопросы. Выберите в всплывающем меню вопрос и тут же получите ответ на него!")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Вопрос-ответы будут добавляться по мере необходимости")

    view = DropdownView()
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)


bot.run('...')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте `timeout=None` в `super().__init__`:

```
class DropdownView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

        self.add_item(Dropdown())
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте параметр `timeout=None` в `super() __init__` вашего `DropdownView` - дефолтно клавиатуры работают только 3 минуты.